# Can you benefit from the +maximal speed while gliding around?

Tags: prototype-2

I saw that you can upgrade your maximal speed and the time needed to get to the maximal speed. Now if you obtain them, does this increase the gliding speed or just the running speed?

Could this in fact mean that you are faster while running around and climbing up every house than gliding through the air?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, but I have no proof, but I've finished the game, and it certainly felt faster to glide when I got the upgrades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, only the running speed increases.

However, once you max out your speed, it is more efficient to run than to glide. This might sound stupid but just try it and check it out.

Comment: Have you got any prove, did it come from testing or is it just an assumption?

Comment: @Tartori Actually, I tested this out. I took a distance on a road parallel to the distance between two roofs. I was able to run faster by like, 2 seconds than gliding over the roofs.

Answer (score 2):

Gliding has always been the faster way even to travel, in the original Prototype. When you get the upgrades for the gliding, you'll see that it's much better than running at high speed.

However, the speed upgrades does not apply to the gliding. Its only for the running.

Comment: So do the +maximum speed upgrades apply to the gliding as well?  This isn't completely clear from your answer.

Comment: @agent86 From the way I interpret it, the maximum speed increases only apply to land-based run speed; gliding both does not obey any sort of "maximum speed" and is faster in the general than a fully-maxed Sprint. That's how it was in Prototype 1, anyways.